# Combining MAC and Encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography

What is the most preferred and secure way of combining both Encryption and MAC. There was a lecture on different combining strategies adopted by different protocols on a cryptography course by coursera.

```
 - Authenticate then encrypt SSL 
   (MSG -> compute Tag(MSG)-> MSG + Tag -> Encrypt(MSG+Tag)
 - Encrypt then authenticate IPSEC
   (MSG -> encrypt(MSG) -> compute Tag(encrypted MSG) -> encrypted MSG + tag)
 - Encrypt and authenticate SSH 
   (MSG -> encrypt(MSG) -> compute Tag(MSG) -> encrypted MSG + tag
```

The lecture concluded with IPSEC approach being the correct implement but i still lacks mathematical background and why SSL approach is not preferred.

Comment: Another option would be to use a authenticated mode like GCM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preferred way is to use an encryption mode which does the hard work for you; these are [authenticated encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption). Usual recommendations are [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) and [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode).

If you are stuck with "classical" encryption, and an additional MAC (and you are designing your own protocol, which is a daunting task), then the theoretically "good" way is to apply the MAC on the encrypted data. This is called "encrypt-then-MAC". See [this question on crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac). As a summary, when you apply the MAC on the encrypted data, then whatever the MAC does cannot reveal anything on the plaintext data, and, similarly, since you verify the MAC *before* decrypting, then this will protect you against many chosen ciphertext attacks (when the attackers feeds you with cunningly crafted so-called "ciphertext" and observes your reactions).